# Unity - null reference exception error when creating new array

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine

I have a script that should be generating an array of random animations, whenever the array is set to a new animation array an error is popping up. weapons is a scriptableObject class that contains an empty animation array.

```
    [SerializeField]
    AnimationCollections animationCollections;
    public WeaponObject[] MakeWeapons()
    { 
       WeaponObject[] weapons = new WeaponObject[2];

        for (int i = 0; i < weapons.Length; i++)
        {
                  // this is where unity says the error is
            weapons[i].Attacks = new AnimationClip[(Random.Range(2, 5) * 2)]; 
            weapons[i].attackBlends = new float[weapons[i].Attacks.Length / 2];
            for (int z = 0; z < weapons[i].Attacks.Length; z++)
            {
                weapons[i].Attacks[z] = animationCollections.animations[Random.Range(0, animationCollections.animations.Length)];
                if (weapons[i].attackBlends.Length < z)
                {
                    weapons[i].attackBlends[z] = Random.Range(0f, 1f);
                }
            }
        }

        return weapons;
    }
```

if anyone could help i'd really appriciate it!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Avoiding null reference exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1943465/avoiding-null-reference-exceptions)

Answer (score 2):

You have to initialize the elements of the array, until you do that, they will be null. Therefore invoking their members will throw a NullReferenceException.

You should add e.g

```
weapons[i] = new WeaponObject();
```

Comment: this worked thanks! i assumed when it made the array it would initialize the weapon object for me

Comment: @MadamePigeon nope it doesn't.. except your `Waypoint` is a `struct` value type ;)